# Replace &#10; with <br>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to replace feed line characters `&#10;` with `<br>` but for the life of my can't get it to work. Please see my code below and the jsfiddle for a working demo.

#### HTML

```
<p id="testText">Test Test &#10; Test</p>
```

#### Javascript

```
var $text = $('#testText');
var tempText = $text.text();
tempText.replace("&#10;", "<br>");
tempText.replace("\n", "<br>");
tempText.replace("\r", "<br>");
tempText.replace("\n\r", "<br>");
$text.text(tempText+"!");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kyct/AR2xH/

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AR2xH/3/

Comment: Do you want the text to show `<br>` or do you want the HTML element `<br>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `replace` function returns it's result because Strings themselves are immutable. You just need to set the variable when you call replace:

```
 tempText = tempText.replace("&#10;", "<br>");
```

Here's your fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AR2xH/3/

If you actually want a line break and not the String, then use jQuerys `html()` function instead of `text()`:

```
$text.html(tempText+"!");
```

Comment: This worked. I had completely forgot replace returns the changed value. Thank you!

Comment: Replacing `&#10;` is irrelevant, since `&#10;` in HTML source is parsed so that the DOM contains an actual LINE FEED character. What matters is replacing `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the HTML instead of simply replacing the text. So you replace the text first and then set the HTML

http://jsfiddle.net/AR2xH/8/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var $text = $('#testText');
    var tempText = $text.text();
    tempText = tempText.replace("&#10;", "<br>");
    tempText = tempText.replace("\n", "<br>");
    tempText = tempText.replace("\r", "<br>");
    tempText = tempText.replace("\n\r", "<br>");
    $text.html(tempText+"!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've [Updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AR2xH/2/):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var $text = $('#testText');
  var tempText = $text.text();
  tempText = tempText.replace("&#10;", "<br>");
  tempText = tempText.replace("\n", "<br>");
  tempText = tempText.replace("\r", "<br>");
  tempText = tempText.replace("\n\r", "<br>");
  $text.text(tempText+"!");
});
```

I added waiting for the document to load, and to set the value of tempText to the replaced value.

Comment: OP surely want line break instead of raw `<br>`

Comment: So you're assuming the OP wants an HTML element `<br>`.  I didn't make that assumption as that is not what was stated, as he specificlaly is using `.text()` and not `.html()`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips For sure OP wants the actual line break since the html entity is a line break. Or else why would he want the br there

Comment: Maybe he wants to display HTMl for someone to copy, the only person who really knows is the OP. It is a good learning process for anyone to realize that when they ask a question, if they aren't specific enough they may not end up with what they want.

Answer (score -1):

```
var $text = $('#testText');
var tempText = $text.text();
tempText = tempText.replace("&#10;", "<br>");
tempText = tempText.replace("\n", "<br>");
tempText = tempText.replace("\r", "<br>");
tempText = tempText.replace("\n\r", "<br>");
$text.text(tempText+"!");
```

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery `text` function automatically escapes any potential html entities. Use the `html` function instead, like this:

```
$text.html(tempText+"!");
```

In addition, as Jivings pointed out, the `replace` function does not modify the string in place. Instead, you have to do `tempText = tempText.replace([etc.]);`